# Central extension

Tags: group-theory

Let $K$ be a cyclic group of order 12 and $Q$ be projective special linear group $PSL(4,4)$. If $G$ is a central extension of $K$ by $Q$ ($K$ is normal in $G$), then how many choices we have for the group $G$? Actually I wonder whether $G$ can be a non-split extension of $K$ by $Q$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from a few exceptional cases ($(n,q)=(2,4),(2,9),(3,2),(3,4),(4,2)$), the Schur Multiplier of the group ${\rm PSL}(n,q)$ is cyclic of order $\gcd(n,q-1)$.

So ${\rm PSL}(4,4)$ has trivial Schur Multiplier, and the only central extension of the type you describe is the direct product.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Would you mind introducing me  a good reference to understand the relation between the non-split extension and the Schur Multiplier ?

Comment: Also, if $K$ is an arbitray abelian group, then the above answer is still true?

Comment: Yes, it's the same for central extensions of any abelian group by ${\rm PSL}(4,4)$. You could start by looking at the wikipedia page on the Schur Multiplier. It is covered in the book by Aschbacher, although that is not the easiest of books. I am not sur ehow much is in Rotman's book. It is done in detail in Huppert's Endliche Gruppen, but that's in German. The article by Wiegold in groups St Andrews 1981 is good if you can get hold of it.

Comment: Great. Thanks a million for your help.